# Запись в .txt файл переменой типа long

Tags: java, файловый-ввод-вывод

Подскажите, как записать в файл данные переменой `finish`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Speed {

    private static long finish;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> linkedList =new LinkedList<>();
        List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        timeSpead(linkedList);
        timeSpead(arrayList);
        System.out.println(finish);
        // запись в файл text.txt переменной finish
    }

    public static void timeSpead(List<Integer>list) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            list.add(i);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        finish = end - start;
        System.out.println(finish);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так сами попробуйте для начала.

Comment: `  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("text.txt");
  writer.write((int)finish);
  writer.close();`   думал как так но это не верно

Comment: Всё с `FileWriter` правильно. Потом просто вызываете `writer.write(Long.toString(finish))` и `writer.close()`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Вот например как можно записать long в файл:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    long[] latency = { 123456789000L, 234567890000L, 345678901000L };

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("latency.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        out.write(latency[i] + "\n");
    }
    out.close();
}
```

B вашем случае можно вынести необходимый функционал в отдельную функцию и передавать в нее данные. Либо второй вариант:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/WriteLong.txt");
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

    long l = 65;
    dos.writeLong(l);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      dos.writeInt(i);

    dos.close();
  }
```

Вот первоисточники и подобные вопросы на enSO: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409953/writing-a-long-primitive-type-to-a-file-in-java), [2](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/IO_How_to/write/Write_long_integers_to_a_file.htm) и [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072639/how-do-i-save-a-java-long-value-to-file).

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @АлександрТарновский, если вы принимаете чей-то ответ, отметьте это, пожалуйста.

Comment: Записать нужно только одну переменную, так что `BufferedWriter` тут ни к чему. Можно обойтись `FileWriter(ом)`.